Highlight cells in column if not equal in other column
Highlight cells (range like C2 to I2) in Col3 if not equal range in  Col9
I have tried with:
function myFunction() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 9);
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    if (values[row][0] != values[row][1]) {
      console.log(values[row][1])
      sheet.getRange(row + 2, 3).setBackground('red');
    }
    else {
      sheet.getRange(row + 2, 3).setBackground('white');
    }
  }
}

Result expected


What exactly is your question? How is your code not working as expected?

@mykaf, Added sample.

I don't understand; C3 != I3 and it's highlighted, as you stated. How is your code not working as expected? What exactly is your question here?

There is red highlighted because C3 and I3 is not same value, that is I need.

What does your code do differently than expected? What steps have you taken to debug this?

I am expecting data in array at var values like this: [ [ 'O222', 'O222' ], [ 'D666', 'D555' ], [ 'O100', 'O100' ] ]

You are comparing values[row][0] with values[row][1]; have you looked at what those values actually are and where they are coming from? The indices suggest that they are next to each other in the range, while your expectation is to compare the 3rd column with the 9th column.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

do you have to do this with apps script?

Try this:
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = s.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 9).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[2] != r[8]) {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 7).setBackground('red')
    } else {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 7).setBackground('white');
    }
  })
}

